# Простое среднее скользящее

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

[image: csv-файл]

Нужно, чтобы брались данные из первого столбца csv-файла, код, который нужно отредактировать ниже

```
window = 5

input_data = np.arange(100)
filtered_data = np.zeros(len(input_data) - window)


for i in range(len(input_data) - window):
filtered_data[i] = input_data[i : i + window].mean()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (15, 8))


ax.plot(input_data)
ax.plot(filtered_data)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input_data = input_df['Wind_power_MW'].values
```

Но вообще в Pandas есть готовая функция для получения скользящего среднего:

```
filtered_data = input_df['Wind_power_MW'].rolling(window).values
```